# PyQt - QTreeWidget - Limit the depth on drag and drop

Tags: qt, pyqt

I'm trying to build an interface with 2 QTreeWidgets that the user can drag\drop items between.

I want one tree widget to only have depth of 1 (dragging an item, from any tree widget, on a nested item will do nothing, or preferably move as sibling), and the other with 0 depth (do nothing \ move as sibling if dragging on an item).

QtDesigner got me most of the way there, but I can't figure out a way to limit (or set at all) the depth of the nested items.

I'm still kinda new to Qt (and PyQt..), so sorry if this is obvious..

Appreciate any help you can offer, thanks.

Comment: Unset `Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled` flag using `QTreeWidgetItem::setFlags` for items which should not be used as drop targets (i.e. items which should not have children, in your case).

Comment: Thank you for answering. Setting those flags work great for the initial hierarchy, but after I un-parent an item or drag in a new one to be used as a parent, I get an item that can't have any children.. Also, I can still drop a parent with it's children into other parents (I can disable the drag for parents, but then I can't remove it's children and use it as a child in an other parent, or dragging it off to the other tree widget.). I'm guessing that you can't get this behavior by simply setting a mysterious depth flag, right..? so maybe I need to create signals and intercept the drag\drop?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit the depth of drag and drop of QTreeWidget, you need to rewrite it.

But, if you only need drag and drop on top level, you can set flags of  QTreeWidgetItem as follow:

```
    QTreeWidgetItem *ptr_item = new QTreeWidgetItem();
    ptr_item->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsSelectable | Qt::ItemIsEnabled | Qt::ItemIsDragEnabled);
```